# Refreshing Div Contents Automatically - NO PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh

I've been scouring the net for a bit now trying to find a simple solution to this. I have some html, and within this I have a div that referrences another html page. All I want to do is reload that div on a set timer.

I dont have any PHP pages. And the page loads correctly at the moment, I just want it to reload every now and then. If I hit the F5 button it reloads correctly.... but it reloads the whole page. I just want this one div to reload.

Is this even possible with it being HTML pages or do they need to be PHP?

Comment: If they are HTML then how do they change?

Comment: Once you solve that - it can be done with Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

load your php content in a div:

> $("#yourDiv").load("yourURL.php");

Comment: I'm using html not php. All of my files are html. Does this make a difference?